# Use a variable of another project in Build Events

Tags: visual-studio-2013

I have a solution containing multiple projects. I can use project variables within Build Events, for example $(TargetDir) to access paths and files of the current project.

- Solution 'MyApp'

  - MyApp
  - MyApp.Core
  - MyApp.Setup

I want to add a Pre-Build-Event in MyApp.Setup. The $(TargetDir) would return `D:\MyApp\MyApp.Setup\bin\Debug`, but I want to gather all files from MyApp-Output Directory and put them into the setup directory.

So is it possible to access variables from other projects within build events?

Something like that:

`copy "$(MyApp.TargetDir)\*.*" "$(ProjectDir)\externals"`

Comment: AFAIK, you can't do it.

Answer (score -1):

I propose you build all projects of solution into one folder, and inside that folder create specific project subfolders. For now your projects have `TargetDir` variable with values:

```
MyApp         - D:\MyApp\MyApp\bin\Debug
MyApp.Core    - D:\MyApp\MyApp.Core\bin\Debug
MyApp.Setup   - D:\MyApp\MyApp.Setup\bin\Debug
```

But you can make common target directory, so `TargetDir` value:

```
MyApp         - D:\MyApp\Debug\MyApp\bin
MyApp.Core    - D:\MyApp\Debug\MyApp.Core\bin
MyApp.Setup   - D:\MyApp\Debug\MyApp.Setup\bin
```

And in Pre-Build-Event you can refer to it:

```
copy "$(TargetDir)\..\MyApp\*.*" "$(ProjectDir)\externals"
```